# How to document.write multiple variables at once?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a loop that will declare a new variable each time. I want to write my results to a new window and I would like every string declared to print with breaks.

I did try making combining all vars together with '+' signs (using [i] to get the number of occurrences) but document.write printed it because it was a string.

Does anyone know what I can do? I'm sure there must be a few ways but I've been stuck on this for a while.

```
window['question'+i] = "some stuff";

    var myWindow = window.open("", "Questions", "width=500,height=600");
    myWindow.document.write(
    question0 + ("<br>") +
    question1 + ("<br>") +
    question2 + ("<br>") +
    question3 + ("<br>") 
    ...
)
```

Comment: Why don't you use an array instead of creating new variables in a loop,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to not use different variables. Array's are made for these kind of things and provide functions to do this a lot easier. See this snippet below how to store the texts from a loop in an array and easy print it splitted by a `<br>` using the join function.

```js
var values = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  values.push("<span>value " + i + "</span>");
}

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = values.join("<br>");

//If you really want to use document.write()
//document.write(values.join("<br>"));
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Right, this is the better and proper way to print data in browser.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for including the document.write option!